# Exclude dependee ASP.NET Core web project assets from publish

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild, csproj

I have three ASP.NET Core 7 projects:

- `Common`: library project. Other projects depend upon it.
- `Web`: razor pages project. Depends on `Common`.
- `Migrator`: console project. Depends on `Common`, and `Web` (via `ProjectReference`) for db contexts, etc. It is used internally only, for migrations and other tasks.
- All are published as "self-contained" and "single-file".

`Migrator.csproj` contains:

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="../Common/Common.csproj" />
<ProjectReference Include="../Web/Web.csproj" />
```

In my CI system, `dotnet publish Migrator.csproj` produces:

```
Pages/                   <----- unwanted
  Foo/
    Page1.cshtml
    Page2.cshtml
  Bar/
    Page1.cshtml
  etc...
appsettings.json         <----- from Web rather than Migrator
Migrator
Web                      <----- unwanted
Web.runtimeconfig.json   <----- unwanted
```

The `Web` project's assets are included in the `Migrator` project's published output, and it overwrites `Migrator`'s `appsettings.json` with the one from `Web`. Note the same does not apply for the `Common` project's assets (which are contained within the `Migrator` executable).

I tried to exclude those extra assets in `Migrator.csproj`, without success:

```xml
<Content Update="Web*.*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
<Content Update="wwwroot/**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
```

I also tried:

```xml
<Content Remove="Web*.*" />
<Content Remove="Pages/**" />
```

I also tried:

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="../Common/Common.csproj" />
<ProjectReference Include="../Web/Web.csproj" ><IncludeAssets>none</IncludeAssets></ProjectReference>
```

How can I exclude those unnecessary assets?

Answer (score -1):

Below is an example to exclude appsettings.json, you can modify the web code like :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="appsettings.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="appsettings.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**OR:**

1.In the Solution Explorer window, right-click the file, and then click Properties.

2.In the Properties window, in the Build Action row, select None

You can read [Excluding Specific Files and Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment#excluding-specific-files-and-folders)  to know more.

Comment: Thanks! However, this isn't what I'm trying to do. This will prevent publishing Web's assets - all the time. What I want to do is to prevent publishing Web's assets only when it is a dependency of Migrator.